# Knockout.js Data is not showing in table

Tags: knockout.js

I have honestly tried to resolve it myself.  It's a very simple try, but Ican't make it work!
Now, time to ask my question here.

Problem: observable data is not displayed in table.

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetSubscriptionInfo", new AjaxOptions
      {
           HttpMethod = "POST",
           OnSuccess = "ListsReceived"
      }))
```

Getting the data from the server, here is the list:

```
data: "[{"ListID":1,"ListName":"one list ","ListDescription":"one list description","OptIn":true},{"ListID":2,"ListName":"two list ","ListDescription":"two list description","OptIn":false},{"ListID":3,"ListName":"three list ","ListDescription":"three list description","OptIn":true},{"ListID":4,"ListName":"four list ","ListDescription":"four list description","OptIn":false},{"ListID":5,"ListName":"five list ","ListDescription":"five list description","OptIn":false},{"ListID":6,"ListName":"six list ","ListDescription":"six list description","OptIn":false}]"
```

At the bottom of my page I have the call back function and data structure defined:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ListsReceived(data)
        {
            PageViewModel.subscriberLists = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
        }

        function PageViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.subscriberLists = ko.observableArray([]);
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new PageViewModel());
    </script>
```

Now, my table:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                <caption class="text-left">Subscription lists and status:</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Opt In</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: subscriberLists()">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="value: ListName"></td>
                        <td data-bind="value: ListDescription"></td>                        
                        <td data-bind="checked: OptIn"></td>                        
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

What am I doing wrong in here?  Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example you declared `subscriberLists` as a "static" variable, which is not declared for an instance of this object. Thats why the data wasn't there for the instance of `PageViewModel` When you called `ListsReceived`.

In your second example, however, you created an object instance of `ViewModel` when using litaral object syntax. So when calling `ProcessListsReceived` you passed data to an object instance of ViewModel.

Thats why your second example worked and the first one not.

Declaring PageViewModel like this would however be a cleaner approach:

```
function PageViewModel() {

    this.subscriberLists = ko.observableArray([]);
    self = this;

    this.ListsReceived = function (data) {
        this.subscriberLists = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
        ko.applyBindings(self);
    };
}

var someData = []; //some JSON Data
var pageViewModel = new PageViewModel();
pageViewModel.ListReceived(someData);
```

This way `subscriberLists` would be a public property of PageViewModel. Upon passing data to `ListsReceived` `subscriberLists` would get the data and bindings would be refreshed.

Comment: OK, first of all, thanks for your suggestions.
however I would like to stick with object literals declaration in my model..  It seems that you know your way around knockout, so may be you know why after I have updated my observablearray in $ajax.beginform part:

 
function ProcessListsReceived(data) {            
            ViewModel.SubscriberLists(ko.mapping.fromJSON(data));
        }

I still have ViewModel.SubscrriberLists().length = 0 ??  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ListsReceived(data)
        {
            PageViewModel.subscriberLists = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
            ko.applyBindings(new PageViewModel());
        }

        function PageViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.subscriberLists = ko.observableArray([]);
        };       
</script>
```

If there are no errors with your AJAX call and you are getting the data back in your `ListsReceived` function, then make the call to `ko.applyBindings` after the data mapping is done. More than likely your `ko.applyBindings` was being called before `ListsReceived` and the data mapping was complete.

Comment: Nope, didn't help..
am I doing the mapping correctly here:
 PageViewModel.subscriberLists = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);?